# Access 'payload' of Qt signal in connect statement

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

how do I access the 'payload' of a signal in a connect statement's lambda?

Say the signal looks like this:

```
signals:
  void stateChanged(std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>);
```

Now in the connect statement, I'd like to access the `std::pair` in a lambda, how do I do that? Something like that:

`connect(&sender, &sendClass::stateChanged, ()[]{ use content of std::pair for conversion here; emit other signal with converted content });`

Comment: Think of your functor as if it was a slot. Make it take arguments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give your lambda function parameters:

```
connect(&sender, &sendClass::stateChanged,
        (std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> state)[] { /*do something with state*/ });
```